# how to read Plist data to UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview, plist

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Get Data from a PList into UITableView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8636296/how-to-get-data-from-a-plist-into-uitableview)

I have a plist with Dictionary and numbers of strings per dictionary.show into the url below.and this list of items is in thousands in the plist.

Now want to display these list into the tableview

[image: eneter image]
.

now how can i display this `plist` into the `UITableView`

what I am trying is:

```
- (id)readPlist:(NSString *)fileName 
{

NSString *error;
NSPropertyListFormat format;
id plist;

NSString *localizedPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"A" ofType:@"plist"];

dic =[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:localizedPath];



plist = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:dic mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListImmutable format:&format errorDescription:&error];
if (!plist) {
    NSLog(@"Error reading plist from file '%s', error = '%s'", [localizedPath UTF8String], [error UTF8String]);
    [error release];
}

return plist;
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

dict =[self readPlist:@"A"];
return dict.allKeys.count;
 }

 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {

dict = [self readPlist:@"A"];
 key = [dict.allKeys objectAtIndex:section];
return [[dict valueForKey:key] count];

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

  cell.textLabel.text = [[dict objectForKey:key] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell;
}
```

Comment: Don't call readPlist: method all the items. Instead of that, declare a dictionary in interface file and use it. because it will make performance issue as you said , you have thousands of data in your plist.

Comment: How did you set Delegate and Datasource for your tableView??

Comment: ya...i already done that

Comment: I asked how did you do that?? Is that delegate methods getting called or not??

Comment: sorry 8000 item with 53 record in each item -> 8000*53 = 42400 records in your plist file.. Mind blowing.. This is really embarrasing.. :-{

Comment: than what else I can do man,.... if i store in sqlite it would be the same in numbers...42400

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE 2:** You need to set the `delegate` and `datasource` for your `tableView` in your `xib` or `ViewController`.

In your `ViewController.h` file

```
@interface ViewController:UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableDataSource>
```

Try this code which I have written for you.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    tableView.delegate = self;
    tableView.dataSource = self;

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Filename" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSArray *contentArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];
    // Having outlet for tableArray variable.
    tableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:contentArray copyItems:YES];

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [tableArray count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
   // In your case dictionary contains strings with keys and values. The below line returns dictionary only. not array..
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [tableArray objectAtIndex:section];
    return dictionary.allKeys.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"MyCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [tableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSArray *keysArray = dictionary.allKeys;
    // This below line display the key in textLabel
    cell.textLabel.text = [keysArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    // Below line will display the value of a key in detailTextLabel.
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [dictionary valueForKey:[keysArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    return cell;
}
```

**UPDATE 2:** After I have seen your `plist` in my MAC, I have found out that we are working with `array of dictionaries` in your `A.plist`.

[image]

So I found there is a `bug` in our code itself. Not in the `plist` file and you can use your `8000 data plist too`.. Its working too. I have checked out totally. Now you can get the above Code and start work with.

Comment: not helpful..table is empty not displaying anything.....please help

Comment: ya that i have done datasource and delegate...donno...wahts happening...where to put the nslog ??

Comment: ya i did nsliog("values %@",tableDict); but its coming empty...means only..values..

Comment: in viewdidload ,numberOfRowsInSection , numberOfSectionsInTableView and cellForRowAtIndexPath  ...hey can you give me email if ..its a short code.but imp for me ..i can mail u

Comment: @Christien I totally refactored your code.. There is nothing problem with your code. there is a problem with your plist file. Its really hard to find the problem. I have replaced your plist file with mine. It worked. I think Xcode could not load this much data from plist. Its not even reading your plist file. 8000 records are really much bigger for plist file. Better you go for a database to store your data. otherwise ask with experts in chat room..

Comment: if i take only 2 then also its not working..atleast it should work for 2..right?

Comment: @Christien grab my update code and start work with.. Its totally working..

Comment: but there is still a problem...that..it only displays the key values...is it possible ? that it display both key and string value in same row...

Comment: and if i put allvalues,instead of alleys...it shows the all the strings.is not it possible to ...string and values in same row

Comment: @Christien change UITableViewCellStyleDefault to UITableViewCellStyleValue1

Answer (score 1):

store Plist data in array

```
- (id)readPlist:(NSString *)fileName 
{

NSString *error;
NSPropertyListFormat format;
id plist;

NSString *localizedPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"A" ofType:@"plist"];

// declare your array in .h file
  array = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:localizedPath];    

plist = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:dic mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListImmutable format:&format errorDescription:&error];
if (!plist) {
    NSLog(@"Error reading plist from file '%s', error = '%s'", [localizedPath UTF8String], [error UTF8String]);
    [error release];
}

return plist;
}
```

and then write it in table

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

  cell.textLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"keyname"];;

return cell;
}
```

Comment: @"keyname" would be the key right?? I am using same for noofrowsinsection and noofsectionintableview.but displaying blank tableview

Comment: did you give the row count - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [array count];
}

Comment: ya doing same..but empty table

Comment: ok look i make some changes in my answer. store .plist data directly in array