# Having issue with UITableView alphabetic order

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have a plist file which contains some names,and I created a `NSMultipleArray` for section's tile which is alphabetic letters. I get  names from a plist file :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
 NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"NameList" ofType:@"plist"] ;
    namesArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

//create alphabetic letters
    alphabetsSection = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"A", @"B", @"C", @"D", @"E", @"F", @"G", @"H", @"I", @"J", @"K", @"L", @"M", @"N", @"O", @"P", @"Q", @"R", @"S", @"T", @"U", @"V", @"W", @"X", @"Y", @"Z", nil];

}
```

TableView setup :

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return alphabetsSection.count;
}


- (NSString*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {


    return (NSString*)[alphabetsSection objectAtIndex:section];

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString*)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    return index;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    NSArray *sectionArray = [namesArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith[c] %@", [alphabetsSection objectAtIndex:section]]];
    return sectionArray.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSString*cellIdentifier = @"cell";

    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell  = [[CustomCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }


    //*** I THIK HERE IS THE PROBLEM ****//
    NSString *sectionTitle = [alphabetsSection objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    cell.DCName.text = [dinoNamesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    return cell;

}
```

The problem is only names with letter A shows in sections. I don't know how add `namesArray` to `sectionTitle` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a quick fix to get your code working.  In `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
NSString *sectionTitle = [alphabetsSection objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
NSArray *sectionArray = [namesArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith[c] %@", sectionTitle]];
cell.DCName.text = [sectionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

But this will filter the array as each row is displayed, which will be slow: it would be better to do the filtering only once for each section, when the view is first loaded.  Something along these lines:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"NameList" ofType:@"plist"] ;
    namesArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

    //create alphabetic letters
    alphabetsSection = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"A", @"B", @"C", @"D", @"E", @"F", @"G", @"H", @"I", @"J", @"K", @"L", @"M", @"N", @"O", @"P", @"Q", @"R", @"S", @"T", @"U", @"V", @"W", @"X", @"Y", @"Z", nil];
    // create a corresponding array holding the objects for each section
    arrayForSection = [NSMutableArray array]
    for (NSString *letter in alphabetsSection) {
        NSArray *sectionArray = [namesArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith[c] %@", letter]];
        [arrayForSection addObject:sectionArray];
    }
}
```

(You will need to add a property `NSMutableArray *arrayForSection`).

This builds an array, `arrayForSection`, each element of which is an array with the objects that belong in the corresponding section of the table.  So you can then amend your data source methods to use this array:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSArray *sectionArray = arrayForSection[section];
    return sectionArray.count;
}
```

and in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
NSArray *sectionArray = arrayForSection[indexPath.section];
cell.DCName.text = [sectionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Answer (score 0):

=> see below post it will be helps to you more clarification :-

[how to read Plist data to UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13776271/how-to-read-plist-data-to-uitableview)

Comment: It doesn't answer my question it would be better comment it  !